# Dynamic data drop down using Orbeon builder

Tags: xhtml, builder, orbeon, xforms

I have used [this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/databound-select1/databound-select1-unittest.xhtml) to chain dynamic data drop downs in an Orbeon application using the following services:

```
  1.  /xforms-sandbox/service/zip-states
  2.  /xforms-sandbox/service/zip-cities?state-abbreviation={../state}
  3.  /xforms-sandbox/service/zip-zips?state-abbreviation={../state}&amp;city={../city}
```

I have few questions:

1. I also want to create the same, so can you please point me the code where this services are present. How I should write the service in this case?
2. `{../state}` - How it retrieve the state value when it changed?
3. What is the use of `state-abbreviation`?

Answer (score 1):

1. This specific test service is implemented in XPL and XSL, in [zip-states.xpl](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/xforms-sandbox/services/zip-states.xpl). But it really just is a service that gets called with an HTTP GET by Orbeon Forms, and returns XML. BTW, you can easily test it from your browser, and it could be implemented with any technology.
2. Whenever the value of the control named `state` changes, `{../state}` will return a different value, so the URL for the service will change, so the Dynamic dropdown will load again that URL to retrieve potentially new data.
3. In this particular example, we want the "abbreviation" to be stored in the data (e.g. "CA"), and the full name (e.g. "California") to be shown in the UI. Again, in this particular examples, values come from [states.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/us-state/states.xml).

Comment: 1. Hope I need to write three HTTP GET service which return the result based on input request parameter. 2. I know this is somthing which pass the selected `state` in the URL, but want to understand the meaning of `../` in `{../state}`

Comment: 1. If you have 3 dynamic dropdowns, yes, typically, it is easier to implement 3 services. 2. This is XPath: `.` points to the current node, `..` to the parent node, and `../state` to a sibling named `state`. This XPath expression is evaluated in the context of the current node, so `../state` is a way to get the value of another control, at the same label, named `state`.